# What do the values in the ARCamera transform matrix_identity_float4x4 represent?

Tags: ios, scenekit, arkit

I have been experimenting with ARKit and saw that the 4x4 matrix from the `ARCamera().transform` property is very lightly documented and was wondering if anyone had any insight into what each column/row in the matrix represented? I was able to gather from the WWDC video that column 3 is for x y and z translations but I wasn't able to find documentation on the rest of the values. Any help figuring this out would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/

Comment: @luk2302 I read that tutorial, but I wasn't able to find each value of the matrix labeled for what it represents in the context of the world, only what operations can be performed on the values in the identity matrix to change the location/ size/ orientation of the shape

Comment: okay, I do not fully understand, it has been a couple of years since I last had to deal with view matrices. I just wanted to get you started, the tutorial at least contains the right buzz words in case nobody with more knowledge comes around.

Comment: I think I've seen this question before...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the different columns in transform in ARKit represent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45437037/what-does-the-different-columns-in-transform-in-arkit-represent)

Comment: This questions comes up often, here is a [FAQ for OpenGL](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/assets/faq_quaternions/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

given where the camera is in world coordinates (camera.transform), you may want to then use the identity matrix to access the space just in front (along the z axis) of the camera view (another way is via the camera's projectionMatrix and the hitResult test but that usage demands more complicated matrix maths that still confuse me).

eg
    `var translation = matrix_identity_float4x4 // this is the magic sauce here
    translation.columns.3.z = -1.0
    let pos = transform! * translation
    let position = SCNVector3(pos.columns.3.x, pos.columns.3.y, pos.columns.3.z)`