# ARAnchor return SIMD 4x4 vector - what is the meaning?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, simd, aranchor

I work with ARAnchor in my project and I want to get the position (3D) from this anchor.

The code:

```
sceneView.session.currentFrame?.anchors.first?.transform.transpose
```

return me a `float4x4 SIMD vector`.

But what means the separate values?

My vector:

```
[-0.030081563,  0.999284570,   0.022921648,   0.06462159], 
[ 0.574515400, -0.0014799305,  0.8184924,    -0.47270963], 
[ 0.0,          0.0,           0.0,           1.0       ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Apple documentation says:

> The **[SIMD](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/simd/working_with_matrices)** provides support for matrices of up to **4 rows** and **4 columns**, containing 16 elements.

All those 16 elements are designed to provide you with a ***translation***, ***rotation***, ***scaling***, and ***skewing*** for X-, Y- and Z-axis (as well as ***projection***).

You can read **[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45437037/what-does-the-different-columns-in-transform-in-arkit-represent/55695304#55695304)** for further detailed information about 4x4 matrices.

And here's how translation elements look like in 4x4 matrix:

```
    ┌               ┐
    |  1  0  0  tx  |
    |  0  1  0  ty  |
    |  0  0  1  tz  |
    |  0  0  0  1   |
    └               ┘
```

Also, you can read a wikipedia article about **[transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose)** matrices.