# How to get some useful sensor data in ARKit?

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, arkit, sensors

I learn from the document that ARKit is `CoreMotion` plus `AVFoundation`, but how I get the sensor data:

- gravity
- acceleration
- rotation matrix

that CoreMotion provided from ARKit instead of set a listener of Core Motion?

Answer (score 0):

**ARKit** (and its new satellite **RealityKit**) not only contains some classes, methods and properties from `CoreMotion` and `AVFoundation` frameworks, but also some classes, methods and properties from:

- UIKit
- SceneKit
- SpriteKit
- Metal
- CoreML
- CoreLocation
- MultipeerConnectivity
- etc.

However, you can't get any raw data from iPhone sensors (Apple doesn't allow it) but you can definitely use data what access is allowed to.

For instance:

> **1.** A pixel buffer containing the image captured by the camera:

```
let pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer? = sceneView.session.currentFrame?.capturedImage
```

> **2.** The position and orientation of the camera in world coordinate space ( [simd_float4x4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45437037/what-does-the-different-columns-in-transform-in-arkit-represent/55695304#55695304) ):

```
let cameraMatrix = (sceneView.session.currentFrame?.camera.transform)!
```

> **3.** Options for how ARKit constructs a scene coordinate system based on real-world device motion:

```
ARConfiguration.WorldAlignment.gravityAndHeading
ARConfiguration.WorldAlignment.gravity
ARConfiguration.WorldAlignment.camera
```

Alas, but you can't get a pure acceleration data from IMU.

Comment: But how can I map core motion data to ar kit to ensure that two users are using the same world coordinate space https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60507826/device-camera-direction-excluding-device-landscape-portrait-orientation/60508070?noredirect=1#comment107116833_60508070

Comment: If you need multiuser experience in AR app use MultipeerConnectivity framework.