# How do I rotate an object around only one axis in RealityKit?

Tags: swift, rotation, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

I'm trying to rotate a cube around its z-axis but I can't find how.

Is there a way in RealityKit to do this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with RealityKit, but in the documentation I see mention of a [Transform](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/transform) component, which has a rotation property in quaternion form that presumably you can manipulate. Again though, I haven't used RealityKit, so I'm just venturing a guess based on the documentation.

Comment: Thanks! Because of this I found the answer

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**In RealityKit there are, at least, three ways to rotate an object around single axis**.

In each example we rotate an object counterclockwise (CCW).

#### First approach

Use `simd_quatf` initializer that has **angle** (it's expressed in radians) and **axis** parameters:

```
let scene = try! Experience.loadBox() 

scene.steelBox?.orientation = simd_quatf(angle: .pi/4,     /* 45 Degrees   */
                                          axis: [0,0,1])   /* About Z axis */
```

---

---

#### Second approach

Use Transform's **pitch**, **yaw** and **roll** that are rotations about X, Y and Z axis expressed in radians.

```
scene.steelBox?.transform = Transform(pitch: 0, 
                                        yaw: 0, 
                                       roll: .pi/4)       /* Around Z axis */
```

---

---

#### Third approach

Use `float4x4` initializer, representing each column with 4 slots horizontally:

```
let a: Float = cos(.pi/4)
let b: Float = sin(.pi/4)

let matrix = float4x4([ a, b, 0, 0 ],        /* column 0 */
                      [-b, a, 0, 0 ],        /* column 1 */
                      [ 0, 0, 1, 0 ],        /* column 2 */
                      [ 0, 0, 0, 1 ])        /* column 3 */

scene.steelBox?.setTransformMatrix(matrix, relativeTo: nil)
```

Real-world visual representation of 4x4 rotation matrix looks like this:

```
let a: Float = cos(.pi/4)
let b: Float = sin(.pi/4)

//  0  1  2  3
 ┌              ┐
 |  a -b  0  0  |
 |  b  a  0  0  |
 |  0  0  1  0  |
 |  0  0  0  1  |
 └              ┘
```

If you wanna know more about Rotation Matrices, read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45437037/arkit-what-do-the-different-columns-in-transform-matrix-represent/55695304#55695304).

Read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76719789/realitykit-entity-rotation-animation-doesnt-go-beyond-180-degree/76731764#76731764), to find out how to overcome the 180 degree rotation barrier.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! As an extra: Do you know how you make this rotation animated?

Comment: You can use `playAnimation(_:transitionDuration:startsPaused:)` instance method for this. Also, read this useful post: https://medium.com/twinkl-educational-publishers/how-to-animate-ar-objects-with-swiftui-and-realitykit-b14730c4fad9

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. Helped me a lot!

Comment: Hi Andy, I read the article and followed the tutorial but this post works with Reality Composer and its behaviours. I am actually trying to figure out how to make a rotation for example animated in code. Would you know how to do this?

Comment: Create a new question about animation, please.

Comment: I made a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59335075/how-to-animate-a-transform-in-realitykit) about animation. I found most of it mean while but I can't figure out which parameters a translation and scale need. That's the only thing I'm still struggling with.

Comment: Found it and changed [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59335075/how-to-animate-a-transform-in-realitykit/59335076#59335076) :)

Comment: Hi, another question: Now you always rotate around the center of the object. Is it possible to change this center point so I can rotate the whole object for example around one side of itself?

Answer (score 3):

For people who are also searching for this you need to use **transform** and **rotation**.
This needs a **simd_quatf** where you give the **angle** and the **axis**.

In my case i had to use this:

```
"object".transform.rotation = simd_quatf(angle: GLKMathDegreesToRadians(90), axis: SIMD3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 1))
```