# How to animate a model's rotation in RealityKit?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, augmented-reality, realitykit

In my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59294602/how-do-i-rotate-an-object-around-only-one-axis-in-realitykit) I already found how to put a rotation transform over only one axis on an object, now I want this to be animated.

Is there a way to do this in RealityKit?

Answer (score 15):

### 1. Transform Animation

You can move, ***rotate*** and scale a model in RealityKit using `.move(...)` instance method. For a faster compiling I used SwiftUI macOS app – although, you can use this code in iOS app as well.

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ARInterface().ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}

struct ARInterface: NSViewRepresentable {

    let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
    
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        
        let scene = try! Experience.loadBox()
        scene.steelBox?.scale = [10, 10, 10]

        let transform = Transform(pitch: 0, yaw: 0, roll: .pi)
        scene.steelBox?.orientation = transform.rotation

        arView.scene.anchors.append(scene)
            
        scene.steelBox?.move(to: transform,
                     relativeTo: scene.steelBox,
                       duration: 5.0,
                 timingFunction: .linear)
        
        return arView
    }
    
    func updateNSView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) { }
}
```

Read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76719789/realitykit-entity-rotation-animation-doesnt-go-beyond-180-degree/76731764#76731764) to find out how to overcome the ***180 degree*** rotation **barrier**.

[image]

### 2. Eternal rotation using `FromToByAnimation<Value>` struct

This struct will remind you of SceneKit's `repeatForever(_:)` method (but more advanced version of it), if you use the `.cumulative` value. `FromToByAnimation` structure is available for iOS, visionOS and macOS projects.

```
struct ARViewContainer : UIViewRepresentable {
    let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
    let cube = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateBox(size: 1))
    
    func eternalRotation() {
        let from = Transform(rotation: .init(angle: .pi/2, axis: [0, 0, 1]))

        let definition = FromToByAnimation(from: from, 
                                       duration: 1, 
                                         timing: .linear, 
                                     bindTarget: .transform, 
                                     repeatMode: .cumulative)

        if let animate = try? AnimationResource.generate(with: definition) {
            cube.playAnimation(animate)
        }
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        let anchor = AnchorEntity()
        anchor.position.z = -2
        anchor.addChild(cube)
        arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
        
        self.eternalRotation()
        return arView
    }
    func updateUIView(_ view: ARView, context: Context) { }
}
```

### 3. Transform Animation using Matrices

For those who prefer to use a matrix math, I recommend reading this post:

[Change a rotation of AnchorEntity in RealityKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71091627/change-a-rotation-of-anchorentity-in-realitykit/71092248#71092248)

### 4. Transform Animation using Physics

For those who like to use dynamics, I give a link to this post:

[How to move a model and generate its collision shape at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71081195/how-to-move-a-model-and-generate-its-collision-shape-at-the-same-time/71083824#71083824)

### 5. Asset Animation

To play an asset animation (whether it's a skeletal character animation or a set of transform animations, including a ***rotation*** about mesh's pivot point) made in 3D apps, like Maya or Houdini, use an **animationPlaybackController**:

```
import Cocoa
import RealityKit

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var arView: ARView!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {

        do {
            let robot = try ModelEntity.load(named: "drummer")

            let anchor = AnchorEntity(world: [0, -0.7, 0])

            anchor.transform.rotation = simd_quatf(angle: .pi/4, 
                                                    axis: [0, 1, 0])
            arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
            
            robot.scale = [1, 1, 1] * 0.1

            anchor.children.append(robot)
            
            robot.playAnimation(robot.availableAnimations[0].repeat(), 
                                transitionDuration: 0.5, 
                                      startsPaused: false)
        } catch {
            fatalError("Cannot load USDZ asset.")
        }
    }
}
```

To be able to play multiple animations, try [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76599901/how-to-use-multiple-animations-on-a-usdz-model-with-realitykit/76600896#76600896) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63672309/realitykit-playing-multiple-animations-in-usdz-file/63677371#63677371).

[image]

### 6. Transform Animation in Reality Composer

For those who prefer UI, there's a "perpetual" spin behavior in Reality Composer:

[Reality Composer - How to rotate an object forever?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62796099/reality-composer-how-to-rotate-an-object-forever/62798722#62798722)

### 7. Transform Animation using Python bindings for USDZ

USDZ schemas become more and more popular in everyday Python scripting for Pixar's format.

[Augmented Reality 911 — USDZ Schemas](https://medium.com/macoclock/augmented-reality-911-usdz-schemas-367ae40c6950)

```python
float xformOp:rotateY:spin.timeSamples = { 1: 0, 300: 1800 }
uniform token[] xformOpOrder = ["xformOp:rotateY:spin"]
```

### 8. Eternal Orbiting using Trigonometry

Trigonometric functions `sin()` and `cos()`, Timer and counter objects will allow you to orbit a model around any axis.

[Hovering an entity in front of ARCamera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73013224/hovering-an-entity-in-front-of-arcamera/73092340#73092340)

### 9. Orbiting animation

Using `OrbitAnimation` struct you can revolve an entity around its origin. Here's a code snippet for visionOS app.

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        RealityView { content in
            async let car = ModelEntity(named: "car.usdz")
            
            let entity = Entity()
            entity.position.y = 0.1
            
            if let car = try? await car {
                car.scale /= 5
                entity.addChild(car)
                
                let orbit = OrbitAnimation(duration: 5.0,
                                               axis: [1,0,0],
                                     startTransform: entity.transform,
                                         bindTarget: .transform,
                                         repeatMode: .repeat)
                
                if let animation = try? AnimationResource.generate(with: orbit) {
                    entity.playAnimation(animation)
                }
                content.add(entity)
            }
        }
    }
}
#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello @Andy Can You please answer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70890755/how-to-add-motion-to-a-loaded-modelentity-from-usdz-file-realitykit       : You are a great help for the community.

Comment: Hi @Tanvirgeek, I'll try to answer your question as soon as I have free time today.

Comment: Hi Andy. Thank you for the answer. Why don't you use Playgrounds for 3D demos? It's much faster and UI technology agnostic.

Comment: Why not, @Darkwonder?!  I definitely use Swift Playgrounds on iPad. – https://medium.com/geekculture/realitykit-911-swift-playgrounds-or-how-to-create-and-debug-ar-apps-on-ipad-pro-190a6d2e03bb

Comment: I am asking because your answer often helps me, but I can't use it out of the box because I work with SwiftUI. Another reason is that I need more examples to play around where Playgrounds let me do it instantly. If you want, I can share two Playground macOS examples that can be copied.

Comment: Thanks a lot but there is no need to do this as 99% developers use Xcode to debug the RealityKit app.

Answer (score 9):

### Rotation with animation:

> copy the box's current transform

```
var rotationTransform = boxAnchor.steelBox?.transform
```

> set the box to rotate 90 degrees over z-axis

```
rotationTransform?.rotation = simd_quatf(angle: .pi/2, axis: [0,0,1])
```

> move the box to the new transform over 10s

```
boxAnchor.steelBox?.move(to: rotationTransform!, relativeTo: boxAnchor.steelBox?.parent, duration: 10, timingFunction: .easeInOut)
```

---

### Translation with animation:

```
var translationTransform = boxAnchor.steelBox?.transform

translationTransform?.translation = SIMD3<Float>(x: 5, y: 0, z: 0)

boxAnchor.steelBox?.move(to: translationTransform!, relativeTo: boxAnchor.steelBox?.parent, duration: 10, timingFunction: .easeInOut)
```

---

### Scale with animation:

```
var scaleTransform = boxAnchor.steelBox?.transform

scaleTransform?.scale = SIMD3<Float>(x: 1, y: 1, z: 1)

boxAnchor.steelBox?.move(to: scaleTransform!, relativeTo: boxAnchor.steelBox?.parent, duration: 10, timingFunction: .easeInOut)
```