# Reality Composer – How to rotate an object forever?

Tags: augmented-reality, realitykit, reality-composer

I'm developing an AR app for iOS with Reality Composer.

In my scene I have a simple sphere that i want it to rotate forever without restarting the animation every time.

Currently I set up a rotation behavior for the Sphere as soon as the scene appears. The rotation lasts 20 seconds and I clicked to the loop button in order to make it loop.

[image]

Unlucky this won't give me the expected behavior: The animation lasts for 20 second and then it restarts but with a very ugly "lag".

Is there a way to make the rotation forever? In SceneKit it was something like repeatForever.

Comment: Share related part of your animation code that does not work.

Comment: I'm not using code, i just used Reality Composer to make the animation.

Comment: Ok, It is better to remove unrelated `swift` tag to identify it.

Answer (score 0):

### Reality Composer's Behaviors

For perpetual rotation in Reality Composer app you need to implement a `Spin` behaviour to a model. At first apply `Custom Behaviour`, then apply a `Scene Start` Trigger and at last `Action Sequence Spin` with default properties.

The only drawback is a "twitching" animation.

[image]

P.S.

However, there's one interesting [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71081195/how-to-move-a-model-and-generate-its-collision-shape-at-the-same-time/71083824#71083824).

Comment: So there is no way to reduce the twitching? By code?

Comment: I tried to use `Experience.rcproject` file that comes with AR templates in Xcode – in most cases it works fine, but sometimes animation is lagging (twitching).

Comment: Nope. It's definitely a bug. You can't fix it using a code in RealityKit.  It seems there's no workaround at this time. Let's wait for major updates of Reality Composer and RealityKit.

Comment: Yeah the problem is that when the animation ends it suddenly restart with a ugly lag. Same for you?

Comment: In 1 sec loop in this case... Yep, but sometimes with lag and sometimes without. So, I think we need to use 20 sec loop to somehow hide that bug...

Comment: Actually I already used a 20 seconds loop. Need to wait to un update...