# How to move a model and generate its collision shape at the same time?

Tags: swift, swiftui, realitykit

I have ModelEntity in SwiftUI and it moves. But the problem is: when adding `generateCollisionShape` method, it doesn't move anymore.

I want a collision effect as well as moving entity
how can I attain both?

```
modelEntityClone.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)

modelEntityClone.physicsBody = PhysicsBodyComponent(massProperties: .default, 
                                                          material: .default, 
                                                              mode: .dynamic)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this trick definitely helps. This physics lasts forever. ))

[image]

```
struct ARViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    let ball = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateSphere(radius: 0.5))
    let anchor = AnchorEntity()
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {

        let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)

        ball.physicsBody = .init()
        ball.physicsBody?.massProperties.mass = 0

        ball.physicsMotion = .init()
        ball.physicsMotion?.linearVelocity.x = 1.0
        ball.physicsMotion?.angularVelocity.z = -.pi

        ball.position.x = -4.0
        ball.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)
        anchor.addChild(ball)

        anchor.position.z = -3.0
        arView.scene.addAnchor(anchor)
        return arView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) { }
}
```