# RealityKit – Playing multiple animations in USDZ file

Tags: swift, animation, augmented-reality, realitykit, usdz

Has anyone found a workflow to create multiple animations for a skeletal mesh packaged in a USDZ file and playback the animations using RealityKit?

I have a skeletal mesh with two animations (idle & run).  I want to package them into a single USDZ file (or even multiple USDZ files if I have to) to be used in RealityKit.

I have been able to create an FBX for export of my skeletal mesh and the animations, and ship them up to sketchfab for a valid USDZ export that RealityKit can understand.  I do not know how to package the second animation into a single USDZ file and then use SWIFT to playback the specific animations based off of specific events.

There seem to be a lot of posts from about a year ago on the topic with no real answers and little activity since.  Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: realistically, simply change to .dae and then https://stackoverflow.com/a/75093081/294884

Answer (score 4):

#### Storing and extracting multiple Model's animations in RealityKit

In RealityKit you have no possibility to play multiple animations from single `.usdz` model out-of-the-box. Look at [this post](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/131463?login=true) and [this post](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/121189). There is just one animation accessible by default:

```
let robot = try ModelEntity.load(named: "drummer")
let anchor = AnchorEntity()
anchor.children.append(robot)
arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)

robot.playAnimation(robot.availableAnimations[0].repeat(duration: .infinity), 
                                              transitionDuration: 0.5, 
                                                    startsPaused: false)
```

---

When you extract second or third elements from collection, your app crashes:

```
mainModel.availableAnimations[1]      // crash
mainModel.availableAnimations[2]      // crash
```

However, you can append second, third, etc. animations to the main `.usdz` file from other USDZs.

```
model_02.availableAnimations[0].store(in: mainModel)
model_03.availableAnimations[0].store(in: mainModel)
```

And here you can find one more [elegant solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76599901/how-to-use-multiple-animations-on-a-usdz-model-with-realitykit/76600896#76600896).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6599590/andy-jazz as the status quo changed? Are you still

Comment: Sorry, what `status quo` do you mean?

Comment: As in this this still the case?

Comment: yes, its still the case @user3069232  2023

Answer (score 2):

As of April 2023, in RealityKit 2.0 there are two ways to load multiple animations, as described in the [WWDC 2022 talk: Dive into RealityKit 2](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10074), in order to bypass the limitation of just one `AnimationResource` per USD file.

## Have one USD file per animation clip

> The first way is to have one USD file per clip. We can load each USD
> as an entity and get its animations as `AnimationResources`. The
> `AnimationResource` can then be played on any entity, as long as the
> names of the joints in its skeleton match the animation.

[image]

## Create multiple AnimationViews from the same AnimationResource

> Another way to load multiple animation clips is to have them in a
> single USD on the same timeline and then use `AnimationViews` to slice
> this timeline into multiples clips.
>
> This requires knowing the timecodes between each clip.
>
> Each `AnimationView` can then be converted to an `AnimationResource` and
> used exactly the same way as the previous method.

[image]

Comment: Hi there, Theok. I suppose there isn't any way to do all this through Reality Composer, isn't it? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: @MAML I guess not, it has to be done in code.