# Reality Converter – Problem converting USDZ file with multiple animations

Tags: swift, realitykit, usdz, reality-composer, reality-converter

I created in Blender a simple cube with 2 animations, one animation move up and down the cube and second one rotating cube on his position.
I exported this file in glb format and I tried to converted using Reality Converter, unfortunately I can only see 1 animation.

Is there any limitation of Reality Converter?  Can I include more than 1 animation?

The original file glb has the 2 animation inside, as you can see from the screenshot I checked the file using a online viewer for glb and there are no problem, both animations are in.

[image: both animations]

The converter unfortunately see only the last one created.

Any reason or explanation? I believe is a limitation on Reality Converter

Answer (score 0):

By default, RealityKit reads in just [the first animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64226321/importing-and-animating-multiple-usdz-objects-in-realitykit/64231230#64231230) from collection.

```
var availableAnimations: [AnimationResource] { get }
```

Nonetheless, there's a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76599901/how-to-use-multiple-animations-on-a-usdz-model-with-realitykit/76600896#76600896).