# How to use multiple animations on a USDZ model with RealityKit?

Tags: swiftui, realitykit, usdz

How to use multiple animations for a USDZ 3D character in RealityKit?

Play an idle animation, when it walks, when it jumps, etc.

Answer (score 2):

#### Switch between Multiple Animations in RealityKit

In RealityKit 2023, you can switch between multiple animations like `idle`, `dance` or `jump`, but for that you need the same skeletal structure in each USDZ file. To implement it, you have to put all the animations from several animated USDZ models into ***AnimationResource*** collection, and then apply one animation at a time to a character with an identical skeleton. Blending works perfectly here.

You can test my code with [Mixamo animations](https://www.mixamo.com/#/?page=1&type=Motion%2CMotionPack), where each character has an identical skeleton.

I downloaded several animated Mixamo models in `.dae` format two-three years ago, and after that made a `DAE -> SCN -> USDZ` conversion using a code published in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50846627/how-to-create-usdz-file-using-xcode-converter/50867018#50867018).

[image]

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct ContentView : View {

    @State var animationResource: [AnimationResource] = []
    @State var model1 = try! Entity.loadModel(named: "idle.usdz")
    @State var model2 = try! Entity.loadModel(named: "jump.usdz")
    
    var body : some View {
        ZStack {
            ARViewContainer(model: $model1)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
                .onAppear {
                    animationResource.append(model1.availableAnimations[0])
                    animationResource.append(model2.availableAnimations[0])
                }
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Button("Jump") {
                        model1.playAnimation(animationResource[1].repeat(),
                                             transitionDuration: 0.5)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    Button("Neutral") {
                        model1.playAnimation(animationResource[0].repeat(),
                                             transitionDuration: 0.5)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
struct ARViewContainer : UIViewRepresentable {

    @Binding var model: ModelEntity
    let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
    let anchor = AnchorEntity()

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        model.scale /= 120
        model.position.y = -0.7
        anchor.addChild(model)
        arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
        return arView
    }
    func updateUIView(_ view: ARView, context: Context) { }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

Comment: I don’t understand… It doesn't work for me…

[This is my playground](https://www.icloud.com/iclouddrive/02ai5ftzm52T2dCEv0xtjizOw#RealityKit)

Comment: @jeremyjoron, your `Salsa.usdz` file is damaged or corrupted. Or its skeleton is different from `Idle.usdz` file. Try another models – I published a link to Mixamo.

Comment: I downloaded a new model directly from mixamo in fbx with 3 animations. I converted to usdz with Reality Converter and I have exactly the same problem. In addition, when I try the same manipulation with SceneKit the animations work well so I don't think it's a problem with the files…

Comment: According to messages in Xcode's console, we have a problem with a model – `Cannot find a BindPoint for any bind path: "", "", "Salsa_Dancing.Agnes.mixamorig_Hips", "Salsa_Dancing.Agnes.mixamorig_Hips.SkeletalPose.SkeletalPoses[0]"`. I agree that RealityKit is a more capricious SDK than SceneKit in animation sense.

Comment: Oh thank you ! I use Swift Playground on iPad i didn’t view this error. I will to try without mixamo…

Comment: 2024-Export FBX from Mixamo, converting by Reality Converter to USDZ, importing to Reality Composer Pro, retargeting animation from one to another, finally export the Scene to USDZ twice（once a animation）,and using to code up here！I done！

Answer (score 0):

My intention is to present multiple animations in the app, so I place the "idle" and "walk" actions in order on the Blender timeline, export them to USDC, and convert them to USDZ through Reality Converter. Then, I use the following code to extract a single AnimationResource from the timeline.

```
        .onAppear {
            var animationResource: [AnimationResource] = []
            var model3 = try! Entity.loadModel(named: "v3.usdz")
            let definition = model3.availableAnimations[0].definition
            
            //
            let idle = AnimationView(source: definition,
                name: "idle",
                bindTarget: nil,
                blendLayer: 0,
                repeatMode: .autoReverse,
                fillMode: [],
                                     trimStart: 0.0,
                trimEnd: 2.0,
                trimDuration: nil,
                offset: 0,
                delay: 0,
                speed: 1.0)
            
            //
            let walk = AnimationView(source: definition,
                name: "walk",
                bindTarget: nil,
                blendLayer: 0,
                repeatMode: .autoReverse,
                fillMode: [],
                                     trimStart: 2.0,
                                     trimEnd: 10.0,
                trimDuration: nil,
                offset: 0,
                delay: 0,
                speed: 1.0)


            // Create an animation resource from the clip.
            var clipResource = try! AnimationResource.generate(with: idle)
            animationResource.append(clipResource)
        }
```

Comment: Alert！This method will break when making transition between animation.