# RealityKit, Model's available animations array always empty

Tags: swift, arkit, realitykit

I am loading toy-robot-vintage.usdz (to be sure, I've checked the other models too) from apple website into my project.

In the quick look you can play the animation for that robot. But after I load the model, and successfully placed it into the scene, I want to print the list of available animations with the button. It always prints an empty array

Forgive me for the force unwrap:

```
let robot = try! ModelEntity.load(named: "robot")
```

Then, I print the available animations (after the model was fully loaded).

```
@objc private func multipurposeButtonTapped() {
        print(robot.availableAnimations)
        print(robot.availableAnimations.count)
    }
```

But the result is always the same:

[image]

I've checked Apple developer forum and found that question been asked a year ago, sadly with no response. The one annotation was to change **.loadModel** method to **.load**, but that did not solve the issue in my case.

What could be wrong here?

Thank you.

Comment: try Entity.load instead of ModelEntity.load

Comment: Hey thanks, I did, sadly it doesn't solve the issue, the array is still empty.

Answer (score 1):

`ModelEntity` works fine. It prints [just ONE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63672309/realitykit-playing-multiple-animations-in-usdz-file/63677371#63677371) animation by default.

```
do {
    let robot = try ModelEntity.load(named: "toy_robot")

    print(robot.availableAnimations)            /*  [AnimationResource]     */
    print(robot.availableAnimations.count)      /*  1                       */
    print(robot.availableAnimations[0].name!)   /*  global scene animation  */

} catch {
    print("Failed to load a robot asset")
}
```

To add more animations to a model, use:

```
@MainActor func store(in: Entity)
```

#### P. S.

As @maxxfrazer said, `Entity` works too.

```
let robot = try Entity.load(named: "toy_robot")
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah both work for me, I have only seen this issue when using .loadModel, which is to be expected