# Converting Blender model to .usdz format with more than 1 animation

Tags: realitykit, usdz

Has anyone successfully exported a model to .usdz format with more than 1 animation? I have been trying to do this for several weeks through Reality Convertor, but still no luck.

I tried playing with the export settings in Blender and exporting to different formats, but only 1 animation came out of it. Do you know of a third-party tool that can convert some Blender format to usdz and at the same time keep all animations separately? With the glb format, it happens to me that it combines all the animations and creates only 1.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This doesn't appear to be very programming related. If you think it is, take the [tour] and read [ask], then [edit] your question with details. Otherwise, you might find more help on [su].

Comment: Thanks @Adriaan for advice. I tried to elaborate the question more to make it clearer what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, RealityKit 2.0 and its accompanying `.usdz` files support only one animation track at the moment. It's difficult to say why there is such a restriction, but it definitely exists. Look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63672309/realitykit-playing-multiple-animations-in-usdz-file/63677371#63677371) and at [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68362162/realitykit-models-available-animations-array-always-empty/68372207#68372207) for more details.