# RealityKit – Rotating an Entity affects its Scale

Tags: swift, realitykit

I am loading an entity using the USDZ file. I want after loading the entity, I want to rotate is forever. I am using the following code.

```
cancellable = ModelEntity.loadAsync(named: "toy_drummer").sink { [weak self] completion in
            if case let .failure(error) = completion {
                print("Unable to load model \(error)")
            }
            self?.cancellable?.cancel()
        } receiveValue: { entity in
            anchor.addChild(entity)
            arView.scene.addAnchor(anchor)
            let rotation = Transform(pitch: 0, yaw: .pi, roll: 0)
            entity.move(to: rotation,
                                    relativeTo: nil,
                                      duration: 15.0,
                                timingFunction: .linear)
        }
```

Instead of rotating correctly, the entity is scaling and getting bigger and bigger. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a starting transform "point" and ending transform "point". If a value of `referenceEntity` (relativeTo) argument equal to `nil` it means `relative to world space`. Since the same [4x4 matrix](https://medium.com/macoclock/augmented-reality-911-transform-matrix-4x4-af91a9718246) slots are used for rotation values ​​as for scaling, when the model is rotated, its scale also changes at the same time, if there is a difference in scale.

For [perpetual transform animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59335075/how-to-animate-a-models-rotation-in-realitykit/59336962#59336962) use some of RealityKit 2.0 tricks.

And, of course, there is a [Trigonometry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73013224/hovering-an-entity-in-front-of-arcamera/73092340#73092340) that was really conceived for perpetual orbiting.

Here's a correct version of your code:

```
import UIKit
import RealityKit
import Combine

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var arView: ARView!
    var cancellable: Cancellable? = nil
    let anchor = AnchorEntity()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        cancellable = ModelEntity.loadAsync(named: "drummer.usdz").sink { _ in
                self.cancellable?.cancel()
            } receiveValue: { entity in
                self.anchor.addChild(entity)
                self.arView.scene.addAnchor(self.anchor)
                    
                let rotation = Transform(pitch: 0, yaw: .pi, roll: 0)
                entity.move(to: rotation,
                    relativeTo: entity,
                      duration: 5.0,
                timingFunction: .linear)
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Does RealityKit provides anything related to repeatForever, so the animation repeats forever.

Comment: Answer is updated.

Answer (score 1):

I made a swift package a couple of years ago, RealityUI, which does include animations like a continuous rotation:

https://github.com/maxxfrazer/RealityUI/wiki/Animations#spin

[image]

You'd just need to include the package, and call:

```swift
entity.ruiSpin(by: [0, 1, 0], period: 1)
```

docs here:
https://maxxfrazer.github.io/RealityUI/Extensions/Entity.html#/s:10RealityKit6EntityC0A2UIE7ruiSpin2by6period5times10completionys5SIMD3VySfG_SdSiyycSgtF