# ARKIt and RealityKit – Why in Camera matrix last line always zero?

Tags: augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit, simd, realitykit

I have started a new Augmented Reality Project using Xcode's default template.

I have made `arView.session.delegate = self`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Load the "Box" scene from the "Experience" Reality File
    let boxAnchor = try! Experience.loadBox()

    // Add the box anchor to the scene
    arView.scene.anchors.append(boxAnchor)

    arView.session.delegate = self
}
```

and added this delegate method where I am printing the camera transform

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
    print(frame.camera.transform)
}
```

The printing is like this:

```
simd_float4x4([[-0.99477124, -0.02513871, 0.09898488, 0.0], 
               [0.04075573, -0.98642635, 0.15906614, 0.0], 
               [0.09364258, 0.16226865, 0.9822931, 0.0], 
               [-0.031830817, -0.025311433, 0.007536184, 1.0]])
```

This printing is listing the columns, right? and the column order is `x`, `y`, `z`, and `w`, right?

If so, the last line of that matrix is always `0 0 0 1`.

Why? What is this line representing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`simd_float4x4` structure represents four **columns** with the following indices: `0`, `1`, `2`, and `3`. The last column with index 3 holds translation values for `x`, `y` and `z`. The fourth element in the last column is not like `w` in quaternions, it stands for ***homogeneous coordinates***. Three diagonal `1` values are scale for `x`, `y`, and `z` axis.

```
┌               ┐
|  1  0  0  tx  |
|  0  1  0  ty  |
|  0  0  1  tz  |
|  0  0  0  1   |
└               ┘
```

If you need a more detailed info on 4x4 matrices, read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45437037/what-does-the-different-columns-in-transform-in-arkit-represent/55695304#55695304).

First three values in the lowest row are for [projection purposes](http://www.codinglabs.net/article_world_view_projection_matrix.aspx).