# Apple Vision – Is it possible to obtain camera position from static image?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, coreml, apple-vision

Let's say I have a single photo (taken with iOS camera) that contains a known image target (e.g. a square QR code that is 5cm x 5cm) lying on a flat plane. can I use the Apple Vision framework to calculate the 6dof pose of the image target?

I'm unfamiliar with the framework, but it seems to me that this problem is similar to the tracking of AR Targets, and so I'm hoping that there is a solution in there somewhere!

In fact what I actually want to do is to detect shapes in the static image (using an existing cloud hosted open cv app) and to display those shapes in AR using ARKit. I was hoping that I could have the same image targets present in both the static images and in the AR video feed.

Answer (score 2):

### Obtaining ARCamera position

In ARKit you can acquire ARCamera's position thru ARFrame's dot notation. Each ARFrame (out of 60 frames per second) contains 4x4 camera matrix. To update ARCamera's position use an instance method called `renderer(_:didUpdate:for:)`.

Here's "initial" method called `renderer(_:didAdd:for:)`:

```
extension ViewController: ARSCNViewDelegate {

    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, 
                 didAdd node: SCNNode, 
                  for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    
        let frame = sceneView.session.currentFrame
    
        print(frame?.camera.transform.columns.3.x as Any)
        print(frame?.camera.transform.columns.3.y as Any)
        print(frame?.camera.transform.columns.3.z as Any)

        // ...
     }
}
```

### Obtaining anchor coordinates and image size

When you're using Vision and ARKit together, the simplest way to obtain coordinates of a tracked image in ARKit is to use a `transform` instance property of `ARImageAnchor` expressed in SIMD 4x4 matrix.

```
var transform: simd_float4x4 { get }
```

> This matrix encoding the position, orientation, and scale of the anchor relative to the world coordinate space of the AR session the anchor is placed in.

Here's how your code may look like:

```
extension ViewController: ARSCNViewDelegate {

    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, 
                 didAdd node: SCNNode, 
                  for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    
        guard let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor
        else { return }
    
        print(imageAnchor.transform.columns.3.x)
        print(imageAnchor.transform.columns.3.y)
        print(imageAnchor.transform.columns.3.z)

        // ...
     }
}
```

If you want to know what a SIMD 4x4 matrix is, read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45437037/what-does-the-different-columns-in-transform-in-arkit-represent/55695304#55695304).

Also, for obtaining a `physical size` (in meters) of a tracked photo use this property:

```
// set in Xcode's `AR Resources` Group
imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize
```

To calculate a factor between the initial size and the estimated physical size use this property:

```
imageAnchor.estimatedScaleFactor
```

### Updating anchor coordinates and image size

To constantly update coordinates of `ARImageAnchor` and image size use second method coming from `ARSCNViewDelegate` :

```
optional func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, 
                   didUpdate node: SCNNode, 
                       for anchor: ARAnchor)
```

For obtaining a bounding box (`CGRect` type) of your photo in Vision use this instance property:

```
VNDetectedObjectObservation().boundingBox
```

Comment: Thanks, but can I obtain the position of a tracked image from a single photograph??

Comment: Yes, you can. You are able to obtain tracked image's position from a single photo.