# ARKit camera Euler Angles rotation order

Tags: augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit, euler-angles, realitykit

I'm new to ARKit, and I need to know what's exactly a rotation order for the camera in ARKit?

I googled a lot for this info but there is no clear answer.

Please I need answer with print example of camera transform matrix.

```
(Rx, Ry, Rz)
```

or

```
(Rz, Ry, Rx) ?
```

Answer (score 3):

In ARKit, SceneKit and RealityKit the default node's (entity's) orientation is expressed as

- ***pitch***, or rotation about `X`
- ***yaw***, or rotation about `Y`
- ***roll***, or rotation about `Z`

[image]

Apple Developer Documentation [says](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1407980-eulerangles):

> SceneKit applies these rotations relative to the node’s pivot property in the reverse order of the components: first roll `Z`, then yaw `Y`, then pitch `X`. The rotation, eulerAngles, and orientation properties all affect the rotational aspect of the node’s transform property. Any change to one of these properties is reflected in the others.

**Answer**

Rotation order for ARKit objects is:

```
(Rz, Ry, Rx)
```

Comment: Sorry for bad english, so in transform matrix should be the multiplying in reverse, rx.ry.rz right??? then why apple in its tutorial calculates yaw from column 0 x and column 1 x by atan2, I reviewed Euler Angles document, that's not right... could you help me ? I apprciate you ..

Comment: zYour English is OK. At first read this post –  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45437037/arkit-what-do-the-different-columns-in-transform-matrix-represent/55695304#55695304 and this illustrated Medium story – https://medium.com/macoclock/augmented-reality-911-transform-matrix-4x4-af91a9718246

Comment: For me, explanation in the links is very clear because I got it in OpenGl course, why I wonder then? my question is when we apply composed transformations, for example rz.ry.rx or any other order we could calculate yaw angle from atan2(sin y, cos y) why they consider this values in column 0 x and column 1 x? I wish I could explain my point ..
Thank you @Andy Fedoroff

Comment: Please give me Apple's link showing `atan2(sin(y0, cos(y))` calculation.

Comment: For atan2 formula it's sure not from apple, you can check euler angle pdf https://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/EulerAngles.pdf and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-trig it's very clear, but apple in tutorial https://developer.apple.com/sample-code/wwdc/2017/PlacingObjects.zip check this line in FocusSquere file : let yaw = atan2f(camera.transform.columns.0.x, camera.transform.columns.1.x)

Comment: So, what you need it for? I mean, using this info for Apple matrices...

Comment: I need two things: first I need from anyone to show me after calculating rotation matrix in order of ARKit what these columns contain cos or sin for all angles x, y, z to understand every thing including why they consider yaw = atan2f(camera.transform.columns.0.x, camera.transform.columns.1.x)
Second; although we could get yaw from camera.eulerAngle.y why they recalculate it?
They calculated it based on x angle, is the x angle causes Gamble lock? if yes the order of camera rotation must rz.rx.ry or ry.rx.rz where rx in the middle based on this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zc8b2Jo7mno

Comment: Ok, I've got it. I'll try to answer it tomorrow.

Comment: Sorry @lady, I haven't found any info on rotation order in Apple matrices. Alas!

Comment: Thank you very much @Andy Fedoroff , Anyone else?