# How to center this model in SceneKit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, model, scenekit

Imported a tiger model into SceneKit, but it is off center? Is this something I can fix? The green/red/blue arrows should be under the model?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reposition model's pivot point in SceneKit, use the following code:

```
node.simdPivot.columns.3.x
node.simdPivot.columns.3.y
node.simdPivot.columns.3.z
```

If you wanna know more about 4x4 matrices, read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45437037/arkit-what-do-the-different-columns-in-transform-matrix-represent/55695304#55695304).

Answer (score 0):

you can use `yourEntity.position = SIMD3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0)`

or set the position with editor

[image]

Comment: Thanks AdR, managed to sort it in the end using Blender, although it was a bit of a palaver.